# Samsung SSD performance in Linux

Tags: ssd, performance, samsung

I'm going to replace my HDD with a Samsung SSD 850 EVO. I've seen a software called Samsung Magician that only works in windows. Can I get the same performance on Linux than in Windows? Or is better to use Windows with Samsung Magician?

Thank's.

Comment: Why not the new Intel SSDs?  They are faster then the Samsung.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a Samsung EVO850 1TB under Windows 10 and native Ubuntu 14.04, and I did not experience any performance degradation neither on Linux nor under Windows with Magician turned off. Which means there is no really any benefit using it (I just haven't uninstalled it yet).

I checked sequential, random read-write and IOPS.

According to the help/documentation, Magician does some caching wizardry and this is probably already done by Win10 or Linux, hence the zero benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I use one of these SSDs in one of my linux laptops and it works like a charm. That being said you may get more bang for the buck choosing a different SSD that does not have capabilities only available for Windows.

*edit:* second thought, that piece of software should not really be of any concern, its a good SSD for Linux.

Comment: I agree. 
I have that SSD and the software does what i could only describe as unnoticeable. Linux is still a lighter OS and you should see some great performance out of it.

Comment: Editor does not allow me to fix "buch" to "buck" not being 6 character modification...